# Group Settings API seems to be bugged

Tags: google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-groups-settings

I don't believe there is much to say. Whenever I PATCH or UPDATE the "whoCanPostMessage" setting from "ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_POST" to "ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_POST" the Google API backend just ignores it.

This issue is present from 06-06-2016.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour you noted is a side effect of a known issue, whereby setting **messageModerationLevel** to **MODERATE_ALL_MESSAGES**, causes **whoCanPostMessage** to be changed to **ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_POST**, as viewed via the Groups Settings API. The Groups UI still sees the correct setting.

Unfortunately, once modified, **whoCanPostMessage** can't be changed by subsequent PUT requests. The issue is being addressed by Google engineers, and can be reproduced via the following steps:

1. Set Posting permissions via the Groups UI to one, or both, of the following:

> 'Owners of the group',
>
> 'Managers of the group'

2. Perform a Groups Settings API GET request, in which you'll see:

> "messageModerationLevel": "MODERATE_NONE",
>
> "whoCanPostMessage": "ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_POST"

3. Perform a Groups Settings API PUT request, with the request body set to the result of the previous request ensuring that the following are set:

> "messageModerationLevel": "MODERATE_ALL_MESSAGES",
>
> "whoCanPostMessage": "ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_POST"

4. The response indicates:

> "messageModerationLevel": "MODERATE_ALL_MESSAGES",
>
> "whoCanPostMessage": "ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_POST",

5. The Groups UI still indicates the correct value for who can post to the group, i.e.

> 'Owners of the group',
>
> 'Managers of the group'.

To avoid this issue, I'd recommend NOT setting **messageModerationLevel** to **MODERATE_ALL_MESSAGES**, when only managers can post to the group, as they are the ones who would approve posts anyway.